# SETING CONTEX_INFO() USING MS ACCESS VBA TO - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010

If you please help me I am trying to set `CONTEX_INFO() B` from MS Access but it's returning `NULL`.

This is my function:

```
Sub Connection()
On Error GoTo Err_End
   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

   ' Open a connection by referencing the ODBC driver.
   cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
      "server=enter server name;uid=sa;pwd=enter password;database=enter database name"
   cnn.Open
'    Create a Recordset by executing an SQL statement.
    cnn.Execute ("SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x9999")
    Set rs = cnn.Execute("SELECT CONTEXT_INFO() AS CI")

    Do Until rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("CI")
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

'    Close the connection.
   rs.Close
   Exit Sub
Err_End:
    Select Case Err
        Case Else:
            MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me; I see a "?" in the debug window and hex(rs(0)(0)) is 99.  What version of SQL Server?

Comment: my version is 12.0.200.8 is the last one @AlexK.